# Print the same value many times in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the variable `x` which is a number. I have a line. (`"<name>James</name>"`) I need to print this sentence number `x` times. Can I do it in an easy way? without being complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0 then you can do this ...

```
<xsl:for-each select="for $i in 1 to $x return $i">
 <name>James</name>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: The select expression should be simplified to `<xsl:for-each select="1 to $x"><name>James</name></xsl:for-each>`, there is no need for doing `for .. return`.

Comment: There is a reasonably simple technique for achieving the same thing in XSLT 1.0 - but I cant remember it. Something about counting document nodes. Can any one remember it?

Comment: Assuming $x is less than the number of input nodes in the input XML the XSLT 1.0 way is `<xsl:for-each select="//node()[position() &lt;= $x]"><name>James</name></xsl:for-each>`, that is you simply process $x nodes.

Comment: Yes, that's the one. @Setinger, take note!

Comment: thanks people. what if i am taking the string i want to display from a particular xpath? now i cant do this. it says the context item is an atomic value.

Comment: @ Sean @ MartinHonnen @ freefaller

Comment: I did that using Martin had suggested somewhere else. thanks a lot for the support people.. +1 for all.. ^_^

Comment: Setinger, if the `for-each` processes a sequence of atomic values like numbers then you need to make sure you store the root node of your XML document outside the `for-each` in a variable e.g. `<xsl:variable name="doc1" select="/"/><xsl:for-each select="1 to $x"><name><xsl:value-of select="concat($doc1/foo/bar, .)"/></name></xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I saw you had answered similar question somewhere else. I used that. Thank you. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The following is untested...

```
<xsl:call-template name="show">
  <xsl:with-param name="text">&lt;name&gt;James&lt;/name&gt;</xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="count">50</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="show">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:param name="count"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
  <xsl:if test="number($count)>0">
    <xsl:call-template name="show">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="number($count)-1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Updated to have `<name>` and `</name>`.

Here is an [XmlPlayground of the above working](http://www.xmlplayground.com/Q7ChbQ)

Answer (score 0):

You could adding the following somewhere in your stylesheet:

```
<mydata>
    <x/><x/><x/><x/> <!-- to print four times -->
</mydata>
```

then

```
<xsl:for-each select="document()//mydata/x">
    <name>James</name>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This takes advantage of the ability to include your own data in an XSLT program, and access it through the `document` function (no argument indicates the stylesheet itself).